# Jquery slice work but not hide somes item

Tags: jquery, slice

i have a Jquery slice function used for hide somes DIV elements who contain guide article data....
What i wanto to do is, starting from 12 records extracted, hide all and show only 5 record by 5 records...
It works and hide most part of div but continue showing guide article TITLE from 6° record to 12° record and i don't understand why...

If you look at [www.pcprimipassi.it](http://www.pcprimipassi.it) in MOBILE version you could see the behaviour...it show firs 5 record correctly...and after that it show title for the remaining records from 6 to 12, and i wannot this is showed....all in on the DIV with ID "ElencoArticoli" which is the div i hide and show with slice function...

Could you help me to understand where i wrong please ?
Thanks to all

My code:

for i=1 to QuanteEstrazioni

```
                if not RsGuide.bof then
                %>
                
                <div id="ElencoArticoli">
                    <span data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" data-options="disable_for_touch:true" class="has-tip" title="<%=RsGuide("titolo")%>">
                    <%if RsGuide("UnivocoPag")<>"" then%>
                        <a href="<%=pathlevel%>psoftware/psoftware.asp?id=<%=RsGuide("UnivocoPag")%>">
                    <%else%>
                        <a href="<%=pathlevel%>psoftware/psoftware.asp?id=<%=RsGuide("id")%>">
                    <%end if%>
                    <%=RsGuide("titolo")%>
                    </a>
                    </span>
                    <div class="panel articoli radius">
                        
                        <%if RsGuide("img")<>"" and not (isnull(RsGuide("img"))) then%>     
                            <%if i<=QuanteEstrazioni then%>
                                <%if instr(Ucase(RsGuide("Intro")),"<CENTER><IMG")=0 then%>
                                    <img src="<%=pathlevel%>images/Guide/<%=RsGuide("img")%>" ALT="<%=RsGuide("titolo")%>" />
                                <%end if%>
                            <%else%>
                                <img src="<%=pathlevel%>images/Guide/<%=RsGuide("img")%>" ALT="<%=RsGuide("titolo")%>" />
                            <%end if%>
                        <%else%>
                            <img src="<%=pathlevel%>images/ICONAgenericaGuide.gif" ALT="Articolo in rilievo" />
                        <%end if%>
                        
                        <%=RsGuide("Intro")%>
                        
                         
                    
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                </div>
                
                    <%if not RsGuide.bof then
                        RsGuide.Movenext
                    end if
                end if
        
            next
        else%>
            <div class="panel articoli radius">
            <%=txtNessunRecord%> <%=txtPerLaSezione%> <%=txtGUIDE%>
            </div>          
        <%end if%>
                
        <div class="row collapse">  
            <div class="small-12 columns text-center">
                <div id="loadMore" class="button success radius" style="display:none;">Mostra altri articoli</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        
        
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var x;
            var inc;
            var max;
            
            x=5;
            inc=5;
            max= $('#ElencoArticoli div').length;
            
            //$('#loadMore').hide();
            //alert(max);
            
            if($("#costolehead").is(":hidden")){
                $('#ElencoArticoli div').hide();
                $('#ElencoArticoli div').slice(0, x).show();
                //$('#ElencoArticoli div').slice(x+1, max).hide();
                
                
                if (max>x){
                $('#loadMore').show();
                } else {
                $('#loadMore').hide();
                }
                
                $('#loadMore').on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                x = x+inc;
                $('#ElencoArticoli div').slice(0, x).slideDown();
                if (x>=max){
                $('#loadMore').hide();
                }
                });
            }
           
        });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an article is:

```
<div id="ElencoArticoli">
    <span data-tooltip="" aria-haspopup="true" data-options="disable_for_touch:true" class="has-tip" title="Violazione di un account online; come accorgersene, come prevenirlo e cosa fare per rimediare">

      <a href="psoftware/psoftware.asp?id=VIOLAZIONEACCOUNT">
        Violazione di un account online; come accorgersene, come prevenirlo e cosa fare per rimediare
      </a>
    </span>
    <div class="panel articoli radius">

      <center><img src="https://www.pcprimipassi.it/images/fotolezioni/ThumbViolazioneAccount.png" border="" width="400" alt="Violazione di un account online; come accorgersene, come prevenirlo e cosa fare per rimediare"></center><br>La violazione del tuo account è un problema di sicurezza serio che può comportare spiacevoli conseguenze sulla tua vita reale; vediamo insieme come accorgersene e come rimediare in caso di confermata violazione

    </div>
    <hr>
  </div>
```

so when you do the command: `$('#ElencoArticoli div').hide();`

you only hide this part:

```
<div class="panel articoli radius">

  <center><img src="https://www.pcprimipassi.it/images/fotolezioni/ThumbViolazioneAccount.png" border="" width="400" alt="Violazione di un account online; come accorgersene, come prevenirlo e cosa fare per rimediare"></center><br>La violazione del tuo account è un problema di sicurezza serio che può comportare spiacevoli conseguenze sulla tua vita reale; vediamo insieme come accorgersene e come rimediare in caso di confermata violazione

</div>
```

so all span tag and hr tag are shown (title)

without modifying your logic and if your structure of each article is same (1 span, 1 div 1 hr), a quick fix:

```
  $('#ElencoArticoli div').hide();
  $('#ElencoArticoli span').hide();
  $('#ElencoArticoli hr').hide(); 

  $('#ElencoArticoli div').slice(0, x).show();
  $('#ElencoArticoli span').slice(0, x).show();
  $('#ElencoArticoli hr').slice(0, x).show();
```

Another problem i see all articles have the same ID `ElencoArticoli`, so its not html rules, even if all seems ok, you could have unpredictable problems

i suggest you to generate different id or better to add fake class during the building of html page.

for example if you have class `fake` instead the id `ElencoArticoli`, you could write:

```
  var x;
  var inc;
  var max;

  x = 5; inc = 5;     
  max = $('.fake').length;
 console.log(max);

  $('.fake').children().hide();
  $('.fake').slice(0, x).children().show();
```

*the snippet displays correctly only five articles:*

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
       //add class dynamically, 
       //you cant do $('#ElencoArticoli').addClass("fake") because it stops at the first id
      $('[id=ElencoArticoli').addClass("fake");
      var x;
      var inc;
      var max;

      x = 5;
      inc = 5;
      max = $('.fake').length;
      console.log(max);

      $('.fake').children().hide();
      $('.fake').slice(0, x).children().show();

      //$('#ElencoArticoli div').slice(x+1, max).hide();


      if (max > x) {
        $('#loadMore').show();
      } else {
        $('#loadMore').hide();
      }

      $('#loadMore').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        x = x + inc;
        $('#ElencoArticoli div').slice(0, x).slideDown();
        if (x >= max) {
          $('#loadMore').hide();
        }
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="small-12 medium-7 large-7 columns">

  <div class="panel testate radius">.Ultimi Articoli e Guide passo passo</div>


  <div id="ElencoArticoli">
    <span data-tooltip="" aria-haspopup="true" data-options="disable_for_touch:true" class="has-tip" title="Violazione di un account online; come accorgersene, come prevenirlo e cosa fare per rimediare">

      <a href="psoftware/psoftware.asp?id=VIOLAZIONEACCOUNT">
        Violazione di un account online; come accorgersene, come prevenirlo e cosa fare per rimediare
      </a>
    </span>
    <div class="panel articoli radius">

      <center><img src="https://www.pcprimipassi.it/images/fotolezioni/ThumbViolazioneAccount.png" border="" width="400" alt="Violazione di un account online; come accorgersene, come prevenirlo e cosa fare per rimediare"></center><br>La violazione del tuo account è un problema di sicurezza serio che può comportare spiacevoli conseguenze sulla tua vita reale; vediamo insieme come accorgersene e come rimediare in caso di confermata violazione



    </div>
    <hr>
  </div>



  <div id="ElencoArticoli">
    <span data-tooltip="" aria-haspopup="true" data-options="disable_for_touch:true" class="has-tip" title="Come scegliere la migliore stampante per uso domestico">

      <a href="psoftware/psoftware.asp?id=SCELTASTAMPANTE">
        Come scegliere la migliore stampante per uso domestico
      </a>
    </span>
    <div class="panel articoli radius">

      <center><img src="https://www.pcprimipassi.it/images/fotolezioni/ThumbScegliereStampante.png" border="" width="400" alt="Come scegliere la migliore stampante per uso domestico"></center><br>La stampante è da tempo un oggetto indispensabile della nostra casa; in questa guida faremo un pò di chiarezza sui tantissimi tipi di stampanti esistenti in modo che tu possa scegliere quella più vicina ai tuoi bisogni senza spendere un capitale.



    </div>
    <hr>
  </div>



  <div id="ElencoArticoli">
    <span data-tooltip="" aria-haspopup="true" data-options="disable_for_touch:true" class="has-tip" title="Come disabilitare o riconfigurare gli aggiornamenti automatici di Windows 10">

      <a href="psoftware/psoftware.asp?id=399">
        Come disabilitare o riconfigurare gli aggiornamenti automatici di Windows 10
      </a>
    </span>
    <div class="panel articoli radius">

      <center><img src="https://www.pcprimipassi.it/images/fotolezioni/ThumbWindows10Update.png" border="" width="400" alt="Come disabilitare o riconfigurare gli aggiornamenti automatici di Windows 10"></center><br>Gli aggiornamenti automatici di windows 10 partono da se per impostazione predefinita, provocando non poco disappunto nella maggior parte degli utenti; vediamo come disabilitarli o ri-configurarli
      a nostro piacimento.



    </div>
    <hr>
  </div>



  <div id="ElencoArticoli">
    <span data-tooltip="" aria-haspopup="true" data-options="disable_for_touch:true" class="has-tip" title="Come scegliere il miglior monitor per il computer">

      <a href="psoftware/psoftware.asp?id=SCELTAMONITOR">
        Come scegliere il miglior monitor per il computer
      </a>
    </span>
    <div class="panel articoli radius">

      <center><img src="https://www.pcprimipassi.it/images/fotolezioni/ThumbSceltaMonitor.png" border="" width="400" alt="Come scegliere il miglior monitor per il computer"></center><br>Il monitor è uno dei componenti più importanti di una postazione computer in quanto lo sfrutterai per molto tempo ed è responsabile dell'affaticamento dei tuoi occhi; ecco come scegliere quello migliore per le tue esigenze.



    </div>
    <hr>
  </div>



  <div id="ElencoArticoli">
    <span data-tooltip="" aria-haspopup="true" data-options="disable_for_touch:true" class="has-tip" title="Come installare una nuova stampante">

      <a href="psoftware/psoftware.asp?id=INSTALLARESTAMPANTE">
        Come installare una nuova stampante
      </a>
    </span>
    <div class="panel articoli radius">

      <center><img src="https://www.pcprimipassi.it/images/fotolezioni/ThumbInstallareStampante.png" border="" width="400" alt="Come installare una nuova stampante"></center><br>L'installazione di una nuova stampante può fare paura ma è una operazione veloce e spesso automatica che necessita di pochi minuti.



    </div>
    <hr>
  </div>



  <div id="ElencoArticoli">
    <span data-tooltip="" aria-haspopup="true" data-options="disable_for_touch:true" class="has-tip" title="I migliori servizi cloud gratuiti per salvare i tuoi dati">

      <a href="psoftware/psoftware.asp?id=389">
        I migliori servizi cloud gratuiti per salvare i tuoi dati
      </a>
    </span>
    <div class="panel articoli radius">

      <center><img src="https://www.pcprimipassi.it/images/fotolezioni/ThumbCloudGratuiti.png" border="" width="400" alt="I migliori servizi cloud gratuiti per salvare i tuoi dati"></center><br>Un elenco dei migliori servizi cloud gratuiti da utilizzare liberamente per il salvataggio dei propri dati foto e video in modo sicuro veloce e pratico.



    </div>
    <hr>
  </div>



  <div id="ElencoArticoli">
    <span data-tooltip="" aria-haspopup="true" data-options="disable_for_touch:true" class="has-tip" title="I migliori softwares gratuiti per elaborare immagini e foto">

      <a href="psoftware/psoftware.asp?id=softwaregrafica">
        I migliori softwares gratuiti per elaborare immagini e foto
      </a>
    </span>
    <div class="panel articoli radius">

      <center><img src="https://www.pcprimipassi.it/images/fotolezioni/ThumbSoftwaresElaborazioneGrafica.png" border="" width="400" alt="I migliori softwares gratuiti per elaborare immagini e foto"></center><br>Una presentazione dei migliori softwares free o open source da scaricare e utilizzare liberamente per l'elaborazione di foto e immagini che non hanno niente da invidiare ai prodotti commerciali e con i quali potrai dare libero sfogo alla tua creatività.



    </div>
    <hr>
  </div>



  <div id="ElencoArticoli">
    <span data-tooltip="" aria-haspopup="true" data-options="disable_for_touch:true" class="has-tip" title="Come salvare documenti in formato universale con LibreOffice e OpenOffice">

      <a href="psoftware/psoftware.asp?id=384">
        Come salvare documenti in formato universale con LibreOffice e OpenOffice
      </a>
    </span>
    <div class="panel articoli radius">

      <center><img src="https://www.pcprimipassi.it/images/fotolezioni/ThumbDocumentiUniversali.png" border="" width="400" alt="Come salvare documenti in formato universale con LibreOffice e OpenOffice"></center><br>Impostiamo le suite da ufficio open source in modo da salvare i documenti in un formato universalmente compatibile e riconosciuto.



    </div>
    <hr>
  </div>



  <div id="ElencoArticoli">
    <span data-tooltip="" aria-haspopup="true" data-options="disable_for_touch:true" class="has-tip" title="Come sostituire la scheda wifi di un notebook">

      <a href="psoftware/psoftware.asp?id=383">
        Come sostituire la scheda wifi di un notebook
      </a>
    </span>
    <div class="panel articoli radius">

      <center><img src="https://www.pcprimipassi.it/images/fotolezioni/ThumbSchedaWifiNotebook.png" border="" width="400" alt="Come sostituire la scheda wifi di un notebook"></center><br>Vediamo insieme i passaggi per individuare e sostituire la scheda wifi/wireless di un notebook o per aggiungerne una esterna.



    </div>
    <hr>
  </div>



  <div id="ElencoArticoli">
    <span data-tooltip="" aria-haspopup="true" data-options="disable_for_touch:true" class="has-tip" title="Come dare nuova vita ad un vecchio computer">

      <a href="psoftware/psoftware.asp?id=NuovaVitaVecchioPC">
        Come dare nuova vita ad un vecchio computer
      </a>
    </span>
    <div class="panel articoli radius">

      <center><img src="https://www.pcprimipassi.it/images/fotolezioni/ThumbNuovaVitaVecchioComputer.png" border="" width="400" alt="Come dare nuova vita ad un vecchio computer"></center><br>Hai un vecchio computer da rimettere in sesto perchè diventato troppo lento e quindi vuoi velocizzarlo ? Puoi farlo con una spesa minima, basta sapere cosa fare.



    </div>
    <hr>
  </div>



  <div id="ElencoArticoli">
    <span data-tooltip="" aria-haspopup="true" data-options="disable_for_touch:true" class="has-tip" title="Differenze tra le varie licenze softwares in commercio">

      <a href="psoftware/psoftware.asp?id=380">
        Differenze tra le varie licenze softwares in commercio
      </a>
    </span>
    <div class="panel articoli radius">

      <center><img src="https://www.pcprimipassi.it/images/fotolezioni/ThumbLicenzeSoftwares.png" border="" width="400" alt="Differenze tra le varie licenze softwares in commercio"></center><br>Capire la differenza tra i vari tipi di licenze commerciali disponibili per un software è importante per poter scegliere quella che più si adatta alle tue esigenze: vediamo insieme di capire quali sono e a cosa danno diritto.



    </div>
    <hr>
  </div>



  <div id="ElencoArticoli">
    <span data-tooltip="" aria-haspopup="true" data-options="disable_for_touch:true" class="has-tip" title="Passiamo da un PC ad un Mini PC">

      <a href="psoftware/psoftware.asp?id=MiniPc">
        Passiamo da un PC ad un Mini PC
      </a>
    </span>
    <div class="panel articoli radius">

      <center><img src="https://www.pcprimipassi.it/images/fotolezioni/ThumbMiniPc.png" border="" width="400" alt="Passiamo da un PC ad un Mini PC"></center><br>Forse non sai che esistono computers cosi piccoli da essere poco più grandi della tua mano e che puoi utilizzarli sul tuo televisore e portarli dove vuoi con notevoli vantaggi: basso costo, scarsissimo consumo energetico, zero rumore, portabilità incredibile.




    </div>
    <hr>
  </div>



  <div class="row collapse">
    <div class="small-12 columns text-center">
      <div id="loadMore" class="button success radius" style="display:none;">Mostra altri articoli</div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var x;
      var inc;
      var max;

      x = 5;
      inc = 5;
      max = $('#ElencoArticoli div').length;

      //$('#loadMore').hide();
      //alert(max);

      if ($("#costolehead").is(":hidden")) {
        $('#ElencoArticoli div').hide();
        $('#ElencoArticoli div').slice(0, x).show();
        //$('#ElencoArticoli div').slice(x+1, max).hide();


        if (max > x) {
          $('#loadMore').show();
        } else {
          $('#loadMore').hide();
        }

        $('#loadMore').on('click', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          x = x + inc;
          $('#ElencoArticoli div').slice(0, x).slideDown();
          if (x >= max) {
            $('#loadMore').hide();
          }
        });
      }

    });

  </script>



  <div id="AltriArticoli" class="panel dalforum radius center">
    <a href="psoftware/PsoftwareSez.asp">* VEDI ALTRE GUIDE *</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

So in conclusion, you have all informations why you have errors

Comment: 0

I use your solution with added class and children object....it work perfectly, thank you thank you thank you Frenchy !!!!

Answer (score 0):

I use your solution with added class and children object....it work perfectly, thank you thank you thank you **Frenchy** !!!!